# How to go to bios in Asus PRIME Z690-P?

Tags: motherboard

I have tried to click <kbd>F2</kbd> and I have also tried to click <kbd>Delete</kbd>, after restarting but that doesn't bring me to BIOS.

How to go to bios in Asus PRIME Z690-P?

Comment: Generally, you have to time it precisely or just sit on the key.

Comment: @user Dude, you should try **HARDER**

Comment: Are you using any USB Hubs to plug in your keyboard or is it directly connected to the board's USB port? Try another port as well. Is there any OS like Windows or Linux installed or it's just a bare minimum PC right now? If Windows 10 or above, also try to Boot to UEFI (still being called BIOS) from Advance startup options and check if it lands in the UEFI Setup or not? Is the Startup logo visible when PC starts?

Answer (score 0):

#### Entering BIOS at startup

> To enter BIOS Setup at startup, press <kbd>Delete</kbd> or
> <kbd>F2</kbd> during the Power-On Self Test (POST). If you do not
> press <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>, POST continues with its
> routines.

#### Entering BIOS Setup after POST

> To enter BIOS Setup after POST:
>
> - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> simultaneously.
> - Press the reset button on the system chassis.
> - Press the power button to turn the system off then back on.    Do this option only if you failed to enter BIOS Setup using the first two
>   options.
>
> After doing either of the three options, press <kbd>Delete</kbd> key
> to enter BIOS.

Source: [Bios Setup Program - Asus PRIME Z690-P WIFI D4 User Manual [Page 56] | ManualsLib](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/2336812/Asus-Prime-Z690-P-Wifi-D4.html?page=56)